# Copying Files Across Network Locations Fast in Debug but Slow With Built Windows Form Application

Tags: c#

```
public partial class ImageCopier : Form {
        private BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
        public ImageCopier() {
            InitializeComponent();
            //backgroundWorker.DoWork += Copier_DoWork;
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            string[] accounts = Directory.GetDirectories("photolocation", "???").Select(d => new DirectoryInfo(d).Name).ToArray();
            accountBox.Items.AddRange(accounts);
        }

        private void copyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            if (accountBox.SelectedItems.Count == 0) {
                MessageBox.Show("You must select an account.");
            }
            else {
                for (int i = 0; i < accountBox.SelectedItems.Count; i++) {
                    MessageBox.Show("Starting on account " + accountBox.SelectedItems[i]);
                    for (int a = 0; a <= 9; a++) {
                        directoryLabel.Text = "In Folder " + a.ToString();
                        directoryLabel.Refresh();
                        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles("photolocation" + accountBox.SelectedItems[i] + "\\photos\\" + a + "\\");
                        files = files.Where(f => f.Contains('$') != true).ToArray();
                        if (files.Count() != 0) {
                            for (int b = 0; b < files.Count(); b++) {
                                fileLabel.Text = "File " + (b + 1) + " of " + files.Count().ToString();
                                fileLabel.Refresh();
                                File.Copy(files[b], files[b].Replace("photolocation", "altlocation"), true);
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            MessageBox.Show("Computer does not have read access to image server or there are no photos.");
                        }
                    }
                    MessageBox.Show("Finished account " + accountBox.SelectedItems[i]);
                }
                //backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
            }
        }

        private void Copier_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) {
            for (int i = 0; i < accountBox.SelectedItems.Count; i++) {
                MessageBox.Show("Starting on account " + accountBox.SelectedItems[i]);
                for (int a = 0; a <= 9; a++) {
                    directoryLabel.Text = "In Folder " + a.ToString();
                    directoryLabel.Refresh();
                    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles("photolocation" + accountBox.SelectedItems[i] + "\\photos\\" + a + "\\");
                    files = files.Where(f => f.Contains('$') != true).ToArray();
                    if (files.Count() != 0) {
                        for (int b = 0; b < files.Count(); b++) {
                            //fileLabel.Text = "File " + (b + 1) + " of " + files.Count().ToString();
                            //fileLabel.Refresh();
                            File.Copy(files[b], files[b].Replace("photolocation", "altlocation"), true);
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        MessageBox.Show("Computer does not have read access to image server or there are no photos.");
                    }
                }
                MessageBox.Show("Finished account " + accountBox.SelectedItems[i]);
            }
        }
    }
```

The code above is how I'm using it when debugging.  I use the backgroundWorker and the Copier_DoWork when it's built, since it just goes Not Responding otherwise.   The issue is that when I run it this way Debugging it flies through the files and copies them all within a matter of a few hours.  Considering how many images it's copying, that's pretty quick.  However, with the background worker it just drags and I estimate it would probably take 35 hours to copy the same amount of files.

I changed the folder location names for this piece of code, but "photolocation" and "altlocation" are two different network computers and locations where the photos need to be duplicated.  Most of the images are relatively small, 120kb at the most usually.  With a random larger one every now and then.

This is not a huge deal as I just threw this together to take care of an issue that will be fixed after this week by other code, but I'm still curious as to what's causing it to be so much slower.   Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does it even works on release? I mean, you're accessing controls from the secondary thread and that is disallowed, only main thread can acces the interface. Try to remove all references to controls in the background task, pass the data as a class or struct and try again.

Comment: When you run the compiled Windows Form app is it running on the same bug that you run in debug mode?

Comment: Yeah, it works fine on Release.  That's not the issue, it actually works just fine, it's just really slow.  I'll try removing references to the controls though.

Comment: @Gusman I removed all the references, and it's still just as slow.

Comment: Maybe working in a background thread slows the copy (but that's really strange), try to use a Thread instead of a BackgroundWorker

Comment: I've attempted a Thread with no luck either, still the same loss in efficiency.  The really strange thing is that even if I run it just as above, before it gets to the point where it loses focus and thus goes Not Responding, it's still running slowly there without being a background worker or a thread.   Running exactly as I run it in Debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up fixing it by using FileStreams for the starting location and the ending location and CopyTo from the first stream to the second in the backgroundWorker instead of File.Copy and it works much faster, just as fast as File.Copy was working in Debug.

Answer (score 0):

The above code does not make much sense... For example, `Copier_DoWork` directly access UI thread to update controls and you even do some explicit refresh. The whole approach is wrong so don't expect good results!

Also, if your processing is so long, you should report your progress and display a progress bar. And you can use the extra argument to send data to the UI thread like the text you want to update on the UI.

If you would turn on all exceptions including MDA while debugging, you would probably have a better idea of where the problem occurs. It is very unusual that the `Release` version is slower than the `Debug` version.

Either, you have somehow done undesirable modifications to the configuration or are in a really weird case.

Also, it does not make any sense to show message boxes while doing background processing. If that is for debugging purpose, then delete it before posting question if you don't even talk about displayed messages in your question. If that is your actual UI, then you should seriously reconsider it.

Comment: If you had read the above comments, you'd see that I already removed the reference to the controls with no change.    The issue isn't bug related, as I stated it wasn't breaking, it was just slow when using File.Copy.   I ended up fixing it by using FileStreams instead as I said in my answer.  And yes, the message box is for debugging purposes.  As I pointed out, also above, this was a thrown together program to fix a minor issue.   Files just needed to be copied, and now it's working as needed.

Comment: Obviously, you haven't remove all reference to controls. Tell me what is `directoryLabel.Text = "In Folder " + a.ToString();`. **Being slow can easily be related to improper multithreading**.

Comment: I didn't change the code above after removing it, I just removed it from the code I'm working with.